# get the month from a date column with the calculated column

Tags: calculated-column

I am trying to get the month from a date field with the help of calculated column. However I get this syntax error whenever I want to submit the formula:

Error 
The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

the default language of our site is German and [datum, von] is a date field.

Answer (score 14):

Below function gives you month in digit.

```
=TEXT([Date],"mm")   =>     returns 01 if date is 15-Jan-2014
```

Below function gives you month name

```
=TEXT([Date],"mmmm")  =>    returns January if date is 15-Jan-2014
```

Below function gives you short month name

```
=TEXT([Date],"mmm")   =>    returns Jan if date is 15-Jan-2014
```

Comment: :I have german month name in sharepoint list ,is there any way to convert month in Number?

Answer (score 9):

Try to use this one `=TEXT([DateField];"mmmm")`. I usually have error if use ',' instead of ';' in formula.
My site language is Russian and it then translates automatically if I write first in English.

Reference: [Get the month name in calculated column](http://www.sharepointboris.net/2009/05/get-the-month-name-in-calculated-column/)

Comment: don't forget to mark this as answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you shared your formula.  Try:

```
=TEXT([Date Column],"MMMM")
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to write my formula. it is the formula: =TEXT([Datum, von],"MMMM")

Comment: maybe I should write it in another way for a site with German language. it seems that there are some small differences in the formula syntax in German: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

For sorting purposes (i.e. Ascending sort and Descending sort) on the month I usually do the following:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT([Some Date Column],"MM")," : ",TEXT([Some Date Column],"MMM"))
```

This results in the format:

> 01 : Jan

Which then allows you to set up a View where you can correctly sort by Month.

Comment: Christophe blogged about a nice trick to get rid of those 01 02 values when grouping; see http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2013/10/31/trick-or-treat-group-items-by-month/

Answer (score 1):

This will return a number from 1-12 and a Null when the date column is blank.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Some Date Colum]),"",TEXT([Some Date Colum],"mm"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The above link to the solution for getting rid of the "02", "02" values is broken ... however, I have posted a solution for that on my blog which will work just as well:
http://thesharepointhive.blogspot.com/2015/12/render-sharepoint-list-headers-in-order.html

Answer (score 0):

Last date of the month (this works for leap year as well)

`QDate = August 2015`

`=DATE(YEAR(QDate),MONTH(QDate)+1,DAY(QDate))`

Answer (score 0):

I selected a date of 3 February 2018 in a custom list date column (named "Date") and then created a calculated column with this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT([Date],"DDD")," ",TEXT([Date],"DD")," ",TEXT([Date],"MMM"))
```

The calculated column appears as: Sat 03 Feb

Answer (score 0):

When I faced the same issue, ***I have changed the site locale into English, added the calculated column formulae, then reverted the site locale back to German.***

I've used the below calculated column formulae to get "MMMM-YYYY" format along with the correct sorting order for Months (January, February, March … etc. )

```
=REPT(" ";13-MONTH(DateColumn))&TEXT(DateColumn;"mmmm")&"-"&YEAR(DateColumn)
```

But later faced trouble when entries from different years are present. So, I've changed the format into "YYYY-MMMM" using the below formulae.

```
=YEAR(DateColumn)&"-"&REPT(" ";13-MONTH(DateColumn))&TEXT(DateColumn;"mmmm")
```

[image]